# Nuxtjs /Vuex is not working with complex objects

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

I am receiving the following message when I try to change the value in my form, works for simple object though.

**[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.**

I have a list and I need to update a register in this list, so pops up a dialogue modal populated and a need to change or not the fields and I click and save summit the alterations and in case I close the modal without save the changes, the values must be the same as before.

My form

```
<v-layout wrap>
 <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
 <v-text-field  v-model="editedItem.personnel.name" label="Name"></v-text-field>
</v-flex>
<v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
<v-text-field v-model="editedItem.personnel.email" label="Email"></v-text-field>
</v-flex>
```

````
export default {
  name: "TheDealerPersonnel",
  components: { TheContentTitle },

  data: () => ({
    title: "Dealer Personnel",
    dialog: false,
    options: [],
    editedItem: {
      perosonneldealershipid: Number,
      dealerID: Number,
      personnelID: Number,
      dealer: Object,
      personnel: {
        personnelID: Number,
        name: String,
        email: String,
        companyID: Number,
        roleiD: Number,
        company: Object,
        role: {
          roleiD: Number,
          description: String,
          ranking: Number
        }
      }```
````

Comment: I would assume you are somehow assigning something from your store state to your data item 'editedItem'. Could you show how you are doing this.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens not because the object is complex, rather because you are trying to change the vuex state not in mutations,

I'm not sure if its the form that is causing the problem but I'm guessing you are in somewhere in your app you are changing a vuex state....

to change vuex state you must create mutations and commit the change

```
export const mutations = {
    SET_CHANGE: (state,change)=>{
       state.item = change
    }
}
```

which can be called by `commit('SET_CHANGE')`

Comment: Thanks, I am using a modal, I would like to commit after I click and save. When I try to change a field like personnelID works perfectly. I didn't get the problem yet.